# New Activity from ListView

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity, android-studio

I'm working on a music sheet app, and have a bunch of songs in a `ListView`.

I'm using an `onItemClick` method, but the problem is, I don't know how to open an activity depending on what subitem is selected.

The array of songs is `uta[]`, so I can find the specific String with `uta[position]`, but how can I open a specific activity based off of the position that is picked by the user in the `ListView`?

Comment: What do you mean by "open a specific activity based off of the position"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a switch/case statement on the String that you fetch with `uta[position]`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    String value = uta[position].getValue();
    switch(value){
        case "value1":
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity1.class); startActivity(intent);
        break;

        case "value2":
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity2.class); startActivity(intent);
        break;

        case "value3":
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity3.class); startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
}
```

Note: switch/case statement on Strings requires JDK 7, see the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try in this manner in your onitemclick method

```
    if (position == 0) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity1.class);
     startActivity(intent); 
    } else if (position == 1) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
     startActivity(intent); 
    } else if (position == 2){
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity3.class);
 startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView item-click listener provides the view that has been clicked:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Song song = (Song) getItemAtPosition(position);
        if (song.getId() == SOME_ID)
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class));
        // you can then create the logic for all your activities
    }
});
```

Also, you may pass the song to one activity that would load itself based on the song data. For that, I recommend you read about the `Parcelable` interface and how to put Extras in an `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {

      switch (position) {
          case 0:
              startActivity(new Intent(this, first_activity.class));
              break;
          case 1:
              startActivity(new Intent(this, second_activity.class));
              break;
         // and more...
      } 
});
```

Cheers!